# How to make the starting digit 60 in the timer

Tags: javascript, таймер

How to make the seed number 60?

```
const TIME_LIMIT = 60;
    let timePassed = 0;
    let timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
    let timerInterval = null;
    let remainingPathColor = COLOR_CODES.info.color;

    document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
    <div class="base-timer">
    <svg class="base-timer__svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g class="base-timer__circle">
        <circle class="base-timer__path-elapsed" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
        <path
            id="base-timer-path-remaining"
            stroke-dasharray="283"
            class="base-timer__path-remaining ${remainingPathColor}"
            d="
            M 50, 50
            m -45, 0
            a 45,45 0 1,0 90,0
            a 45,45 0 1,0 -90,0
            "
        ></path>
        </g>
    </svg>
    <span id="base-timer-label" class="base-timer__label">${formatTime(
        timeLeft 
    )}</span>
    <p>осталось секунд</p>
    </div>
    `;

    $('#timer').click( function() {
        startTimer();
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    })

    function startTimer() {
        timePassed = 0;
        clearInterval(timerInterval);
        timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
            timePassed += 1;
            timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT - timePassed;
            document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(
            timeLeft
            );
            setCircleDasharray();
            setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft);

            if (timeLeft <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timerInterval);
                $('#timer').removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    function formatTime(time) {
    let seconds = time % 60;

    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = `${seconds}`;
    }

    return `${seconds}`;
    }

    function setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft) {
    const { alert, warning, info } = COLOR_CODES;
    if (timeLeft <= alert.threshold) {
        document
        .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
        .classList.remove(warning.color);
        document
        .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
        .classList.add(alert.color);
    } else if (timeLeft <= warning.threshold) {
        document
        .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
        .classList.remove(info.color);
        document
        .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
        .classList.add(warning.color);
    }
    }

    function calculateTimeFraction() {
    const rawTimeFraction = timeLeft / TIME_LIMIT;
    return rawTimeFraction - (1 / TIME_LIMIT) * (1 - rawTimeFraction);
    }

    function setCircleDasharray() {
    const circleDasharray = `${(
        calculateTimeFraction() * FULL_DASH_ARRAY
    ).toFixed(0)} 283`;
    document
        .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
        .setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", circleDasharray);
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если вы так тяготееете к английскому языку то пишите вопрос на англоязычный so =>  https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: How about Russian? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function formatTime(time) {
  if (time == 60)
    return `${time}`;

  let seconds = time % 60;

  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = `0${seconds}`;
  }

  return `${seconds}`;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked :)